# MS Word footnotes skip numbers when using Track Changes

Tags: microsoft-word, word-processing, microsoft-word-2016

I'm using MS Word's "Track changes" functionality to edit an academic article with a lot of footnotes. The issue I'm running into is more of a 'feature' than a bug but I'm not sure how to approach it: if I have text with a footnote that I delete, including the footnote, Word keeps that footnote number reserved (technically it is still there, just in a not-yet-accepted change) and thus the footnotes that follow skip over a number.

Technically this isn't a problem except that I cannot yet "accept" the changes as I need to submit the edited article for publication with changes included so the editors can see what I've done to improve the article. But at the same time, I want to actually have the footnotes in the article progress sequentially without jumping over numbers. One theoretical solution is to delete the footnote itself without 'track changes' turned on, and then delete the body text, but I don't want to make it look like my work (even material which is deleted) isn't cited properly for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 7):

I've had a similar issue. I sent a document to a reviewer, and they returned it having deleted two footnotes with track-changes enabled. In the footnotes I could see the "Deleted" balloon, but couldn't "accept" the change. Eventually I solved it: (based on Word 2016 for Mac)

1. Go into Draft view
2. Select References
3. Find the "Show footnotes" icon (unhelpfully it's not labelled!)
4. Scroll through the bottom pane until you find reach the "missing" reference numbers (e.g. I was missing "61", so I went to 60 and then read on from there) u
5. Then look in the upper pane, and you should see the original footnote reference  in the draft text, albeit slightly greyed out. Delete that reference number ... and hey presto, the numbering goes back to being sequential.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: the numbering skipped two numbers, jumping from 6 to 9. I tried everything, but neither one of the solutions described above worked for me.

So this is how I circumvented the problem: I assigned the two footnotes after the missing ones special characters (7 and 8). Thus they were not counted as part of the continuous series. Now these two were taking up the places of the ones I could not delete, and the numbers that followed them were correct again.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same issue. Here's what twiddling around that helped me solve the issue. 
First go to the *Review* tab and select *All markup* from the markup selector. You'll be able to see some deleted footnote in red. But as it's still tracked your endnote will still be present. Delete it (even though it's in red) and you're good to go

Comment: This didn't work for me with Word 2013.

Answer (score 0):

#### The footnotes that follow skip over a number

- Insert a (dummy) section break.
- Set "Start at" to the number of the deleted footnote.
- Set "Numbering" to "Restart each section".

See below for instructions.

---

#### Changing the Way Footnotes Are Numbered

> In Word, footnotes can be automatically numbered from 1 through the
>   number of footnotes in the document. Thus, if your document contains
>   14 footnotes, they will be numbered 1 through 14.
>
> You can change the way footnotes are numbered, however.
>
> Word allows you to specify both a starting footnote number and whether
>   the numbering starts over with each new section in your document.
>
> Word allows you to change how it handles footnote numbering by
>   following these steps:
>
> 1. Make sure the References tab is selected on the ribbon.
> 2. Click the small downward-pointing arrow at the lower-right corner of the Footnotes group. Word displays the Footnote and Endnote dialog
>      box.
>
>    [image]
> 3. Make sure the Footnotes radio button is selected.
> 4. Change the Start At value to reflect where you want Word to start numbering.
> 5. Change the Numbering area to reflect how you want Word to count your footnotes.
> 6. Click on Apply and then Cancel; otherwise click Insert to add a footnote mark at the current document location.

Source [Changing the Way Footnotes Are Numbered](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T005973_Changing_the_Way_Footnotes_Are_Numbered.html)

Comment: So you are suggesting that if footnote 11 has been deleted (and footnote 10 jumps to 12), I put in a section break after footnote 10 and then restart footnote numbering at 11?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Save a copy to your desktop for a test (use this as a supporting doc, if needed). In the Review pane, in Tracking select Simple Markup. The footnote numbering will still be out of sequence (due to a deleted reference). Now, in Changes, select Accept > Accept All Changes and Stop Tracking. The numbering will now be in sequence!

Note: Do this step after your reviewer has approved all the tracked changes.

:) Diane

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of your document so you now have two copies.

In Copy #1, accept all changes, and check that footnotes make sense again, in terms of their numbering, and anything else relevant.

Give your client:

- Copy #1 (a clean copy with correct footnotes/endnotes, etc.) and
- Copy #2 (the one with Tracked changes still in it so they can see what you changed).

I think this is the safest way to ensure you don't end up delivering a messed up file.

---

See:

"As per description, using the Track Changes feature of Word with Track Changes turned on. In that case, deleting the footnote doesn't actually delete it, but simply marks it as deleted text. **Word doesn't renumber the footnotes because the footnote is still there. When the changes are accepted or rejected, then Word will renumber the footnotes accordingly.**"

"It is a known fact that **numbering of any kind is not reliable until tracked changes are resolved**."

(https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/footnote-in-word-not-refreshing-when-using-track/abf6f3e6-95ca-4d23-8325-29215cd310d9)

Answer (score 0):

So, after posting my first answer, I discovered what might be a better **solution**, and one **that allows you to keep tracked changes in your document**. I found this solution on one of my favourite websites with tips & tricks on using MS Word.

The answer is from this page: https://word.tips.net/T005400_Footnotes_Dont_Automatically_Renumber.html

The solution is as follows:

"Finally, if you've tried everything else and the numbering is still messed up, try to "force" Word to examine the numbers it is using. Do this by following these steps:

1. Press **Ctrl+H** to display the Replace tab of the Find and Replace
   dialog box.
2. Click the More button, if it is available.
3. Click the Use Wildcards radio button.
4. With the insertion point in the Find What box, click Format and choose Style. Word displays the Find Style dialog box.
5. Locate and click on the Footnote Reference style.
6. Click OK to close the Find Style dialog box.
7. In the Replace With box enter the following: **^&**
8. Click Replace All."

After doing this, I was left with a document with Tracked Changes still in it, but with all my footnotes correctly renumbered!

**PS**: The caret combined with the ampersand (^&) represents whatever text was matched by the Find what clause.